# Replace dynamic generated string using sed

Tags: bash, date, sed

I have a file that I would like to rename using sed. For simplicity purposes, this is what I am trying to do:

```
sh-4.3$ echo `date`
Thu 17 Sep 08:29:50 EAT 2015
sh-4.3$ echo `date` | sed 's/`date`/Today/'
Thu 17 Sep 08:29:58 EAT 2015
sh-4.3$
```

I expect it to echo "Today". What's the catch?

Comment: Take a look at [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside single-quotes, backticks are not evaluated.  Use double-quotes instead:

```
$ echo `date` | sed "s/`date`/Today/"
Today
```

For a variety of reasons, backticks are considered archaic.  For all POSIX shells, use `$(...)`:

```
$ echo $(date) | sed "s/$(date)/Today/"
Today
```

Although it may not be relevant to your larger script, for this simple command, `echo` is not needed:

```
$ date | sed "s/$(date)/Today/"
Today
```

Note that this is fragile.  If the seconds happen to tick over between the execution of one and the other `date` commands, then this substitution will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I eventually will not be using the seconds, as am interested only in the D, M and Y parts, like this: `echo $(date +%Y%m%d) | sed "s/$(date +%Y%m%d)/Today/"`. Works fine and thanks for the $(...) pointer too

Comment: @Benda Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo `date`
```

is not the same as

```
echo 'date'
```

backticks cause execution of the expression encased within them, single quotes are a plain string.

Since your echo is so simple, `echo date` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I preconise to also change the separator, date info could have some meta character depending settings

```
date | sed "s~$( date )~Today~"
```